# Scope of Function variable in Javascript: Looping through background colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work. I am aiming to loop through a javscript file to change the background colour of my html document on click. When I am to do this it doesn't loop through but then goes straight to yellow (the last of the loop)

```
    const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function myFunction(){
    for (let i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
    }
}
```

it automatically goes to i = 2 and creates a yellow background color

here is html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colour Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
        <ul>Simple Hex</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
        <h1>Background Colour</h1>
    </button>
    </div>
    <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please also include what you are trying to achieve ("does not work" does not work). Then read out aloud what you want to do and compare that to your function's code.

Comment: The code works. But it is not doing what you expect it to. Are you trying to see alternating colors? Note that the loop runs very fast and you won't see the first two colors at all

Comment: The browser UI doesn't update while sync code is running. Since you are using a loop the loop runs to completion and then the UI updates. You need to use some timeout between setting the background for each individual change to be seen

Comment: I am trying to change colours on click

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that the entire `myFunction` code is being run on every click. Because your counter is defined in the function, it is reset every click, and the loop is running every time, and cycling through all of the colours, on every click. You're only seeing yellow because it is running too quickly for you to see the individual colours, and the loop is ending on yellow, as it is the last element in the colors array.

If you want to cycle colours on click, you need to store the state of the color outside of the function loop, because your event function should only needs to have code that will run every time a click happens.

Here is how I imagine you wanted it to work:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction(){
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colour Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
        <ul>Simple Hex</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
        <h1>Background Colour</h1>
    </button>
    </div>
    <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry should have been more specific i am trying to change background color on click

Comment: Sorry, I answered too early. I've edited my answer for you. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much this really helped and it works I will look at it

Comment: My pleasure, I've also edited my answer to explain why this code works. Let me know if I can explain it better for you.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly alternative approach to SubXaero's answer is to use [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to maintain a local variable rather than creating a global one.

Note: I've used classes here instead of setting the background style directly.

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.getElementById("color");

// Pass in `colors` to the handler which returns a new
// function that does all the work
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick(colors), false);

// This function accepts colors as an argument
// initialises the array index, and then
// returns the function that will be used as the listener
function handleClick(colors) {
  let index = 0;
  return function() {
    if (index < colors.length) {
      color.classList.add(colors[index]);
      ++index;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="color">Colour</div>
<button id="btn">Background Colour</button>
```